# How to disable selective keys on the keyboard?

Tags: windows, keyboard

I'd like to write an application which disables certain keys on the keyboard while it's working. More specifically I'm interested in keys that might make the application loose focus (like ALT+TAB, WinKey, Ctrl+Shift+Esc, etc.) The need for this is has to do with babies/animals bashing wildly at the keyboard. :)

My first idea was to use [SetWindowsHookEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx), however I ran into a problem. Since I need a global hook, the procedure would have to reside in a .DLL which would get injected in all active applications. But a .DLL can be either 64-bit or 32-bit, not both. And on a 64-bit system there are both types of applications. I guess then that I must write two copies of the hook .DLL - one for 32-bit and the other for 64-bit. And then I'd also have to launch two copies of the application as well, because the application first has to load the DLL itself before it can pass it on to `SetWindowsHookEx()`.

Sounds pretty clumsy and awkward. Is there perhaps a better way? Or maybe I've misunderstood something?

Note that I still want the mouse to work and "simple" alphabetic keys too, so [BlockInput()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646290(VS.85).aspx) will not do.

**Added:** I can develop both on .NET (C#/VB) or on C/C++ and WinAPI. I expect that the latter would be more appropriate.

Comment: What development platform are you planning on using? I believe Scott Hanselman's Babysmash (C# & WPF) does something like this.http://www.hanselman.com/babysmash/

Comment: Nice! Finally a decent baby smash application! I couldn't find one! OK, that's one item off my "things to make" list. But I had another idea too - simply a software which allows you to selectively disable few or all keys on the keyboard (minus Ctrl-Alt-Del of course). This could be useful when I enter an application (game) which uses only mouse for control, so that I can relinquish my keyboard to the little one. I could just unplug the keyboard of course, but the plug at my place is difficult to get to.

Comment: Also it would help against some annoying keypresses as-per-se, like the NumLock/CapsLock, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WH_KEYBOARD_LL runs in the context of your process (On Win9x you will have to stick to the normal hook but you don't have the 64bit problem there)

Comment: Are you sure? MSDN suggests otherwise.

Comment: "This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644985(v=VS.85).aspx